# Is there any std::istream manipulator that consume predefined string from input?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

I've got string like this:

```
some text that i'd like to ignore 123 the rest of line
```

The format is fixed, only the number changes. I'd like to read this "123" and ignore the rest, but verify that the rest of line is in assumed format. If I used scanf, I could write:

```
int result = scanf("some text that i'd like to ignore %d the rest of line", &number);
assert(result==1);
```

And then by checking the result I would know whether the line is in correct format. I'm looking for some std:: or boost:: method to do this, for instance using a modifier like this:

```
std::cin >> std::check_input("some text that i'd like to ignore") >> number >> std::ws >> std::check_input("the rest of line");
assert(!std::cin.fail());
```

Of course I could write it myself, but I can't believe that there is no simple method to do this using only std or boost.

Is there?

EDIT: Regex would be overkill for me in this case.

Comment: there is if you use Boost Spirit... (`qi::string("some_expected_string")` or `qi::lit("the_same")` if you're not interested in the string's value)

Comment: Actually, `qi::match` is an excellent match here, as I've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Boost you can use Spirit's `qi::match` manipulator:

```
std::istringstream input("some text that i'd like to ignore 42 \tthe rest of line");

int number;

if (input >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(
         "some text that i'd like to ignore" 
      >> qi::int_ 
      >> "the rest of line", qi::space, number))
{
    std::cout << "Successfully parsed (" << number << ")\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Successfully parsed (42)
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1cf03220894d966)**

Of course, Boost Spirit is *vastly* more powerful than this, but... it can also be used for quick solutions like this!

#### Full Sample

Code preserved for posterity:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("some text that i'd like to ignore 42 \tthe rest of line");

    int number;

    if (input >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(
             "some text that i'd like to ignore" 
          >> qi::int_ 
          >> "the rest of line", qi::space, number))
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully parsed (" << number << ")\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for string with spaces.

Comment: @peper0 I've edited the answer to match your question exactly. Note `std::noskipws` and the use of `qi::space` to ignore variable whitespace around the number. Cheers